# Bat que pregunte IP antes del ping

Tags: batch, msdos

Buenas tardes quisiera saber si me puede ayudar, necesito tener un .bat que me pregunte a que IP quiero realizar el Ping y que con hacer click derecho la "Pegue" Ej.

INGRESE SU IP: 192.168.1.1

Haciendo ping a 192.168.1.1 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=2ms TTL=64

Muchas gracias, Matias.-

Answer (score 1):

Espero sea lo que buscas:

```
@echo off
set /P IP=Ingrese su IP: 
ping %IP%
```

Referencia: [In Windows cmd, how do I prompt for user input and use the result in another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com)

Comment: Perfecto!! muchisimas gracias!!! muy amable!